# I keep receiving SyntaxError when I use execute_script command in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, syntax-error

So I'm using Python Selenium to do some automation and I used a execute_script to click, here's the segment of my code:

```
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-all"]/ul/li[' + str(x+1) + ']/div[2]/div/h5/a')))
        song_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-all"]/ul/li[' + str(x+1) + ']/div[2]/div/h5/a').text
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-all"]/ul/li[' + str(x+1) + ']/div[2]/div/div')))
        song_author = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-all"]/ul/li[' + str(x+1) + ']/div[2]/div/div').text
        if audio_author.split(",")[0].strip() in song_author and song_title in audio_title:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, song_title))
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', driver.find_element_by_link_text(song_title))
```

The last line where I try to click is where I'm encoutering errors but the funny thing is that when I replace the code with another line that doesn't produce errors, SyntaxError still happen. Is the error because of lines surrounding the code?

Here's the line I tried to replace the last line with (didn't raise errors where it's used but raised errors when it replaces the last line)

```
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form-login"]/div[1]/div/div/button'))
```

Comment: Are you sure `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form-login"]/div[1]/div/div/button')` will return anything?

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, song_title))` is not balanced. You are missing one last parentheses